# Read registry key value and re-use

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to write a batch file to easier uninstall (silently) using msiexec. So, I need to find the value that is in the key "UninstallString". (example value is: MsiExec.exe /X{XXXXXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-YYYY-XXXXXXXXX})

Afterward, I want to read in that exact same uninstallstring to uninstall the program in question. Anyone has an idea on how to do that? I already know the location of said UninstallString key.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reg command will help you to add, delete & query registry keys

```
REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ResKit /ve Version
```

Check the below links

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc742028.aspx

[Get Value of Registry Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213574/get-value-of-registry-key)

Comment: Thanks, will check it out soon